# Host website and emails in different server cpanel

Tags: email, cpanel, server

I am having a client who want to keep his website and mails in two separate server. Both are having cpanel hosting. So can someone help me with step to step changes what I need to do ?

Now www.example.com is having cpanel and works fine.
Have another cpanel hosting ready, So what all things I need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to host example.com in two different server, one for website and another for mail service ?

If this is your question, please follow the below steps.

Login to your first cPanel of example.com (for website)

Upload all the files here.
Then, click "Simple DNS Editor" in the same cPanel.
Under "Add an A Record"
Name:mail.example.com
Address :your_mail_server_ip address (ask your mail service provider for this)

And click "Add a Record".

Once this record added.

Goto "MX Entry"
Choose "Remote Mail Exchanger"
Click Change.

Then delete the previous MX record.
Now Add mail.example.com in Destination, Priority is 0 (zero).
Click "Add New Record"

That's it.

### Solution No.2:

Upload your contents in cpanel used for website.

Now, Login to your another cPanel used for mail service.

Go to "Simple DNS Editor" under Add an A Record

Name: example.com
address : A record IP address of your website server.

Create email id in email server (cPanel) and start using the mails and website in different server.

Hope this helps you.

### Solution No.3:

If this confusing you. contact your hosting provider with MX record and its IP address.

Ask them to update that MX record from their end.